# Convert xml (mixed nodes and attributes) to csv file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml which has mix of nodes and nodes with attributes as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root> 
    <StudentRequestList count="3">
    <StudentRequest>
        <StudentFirstName>Test1</StudentFirstName>
        <StudentLastName>TestLastName</StudentLastName>
        <StudentGrade>3</StudentGrade>
        <StudentHomeroomTeacher>WhiteTest1</StudentHomeroomTeacher>
        <VariableData>
            <Variable name="Email">test@email.com</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby1">TestHobby1</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby2">TestHobby2</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby3">TestHobby3</Variable>
            <Variable name="satscore">satscoreTest1</Variable>
            <Variable name="kprepscore">krepscore1</Variable>           
        </VariableData>
    </StudentRequest>
        <StudentRequest>
        <StudentFirstName>Test2</StudentFirstName>
        <StudentLastName>TestLastName2</StudentLastName>
        <StudentGrade>3</StudentGrade>
        <StudentHomeroomTeacher>WhiteTest1</StudentHomeroomTeacher>
        <VariableData>
            <Variable name="Email">test2@email.com</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby5">TestHobby5</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby6">TestHobby6</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby3">TestHobby3</Variable>
            <Variable name="satscore">satscoreTest2</Variable>
            <Variable name="kprepscore">krepscore2</Variable>           
        </VariableData>
    </StudentRequest>
        <StudentRequest>
        <StudentFirstName>Test1</StudentFirstName>
        <StudentLastName>TestLastName</StudentLastName>
        <StudentGrade>3</StudentGrade>
        <StudentHomeroomTeacher>WhiteTest1</StudentHomeroomTeacher>
        <VariableData>
            <Variable name="Email">test@email.com</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby4">TestHobby4</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby2">TestHobby2</Variable>
            <Variable name="Hobby3">TestHobby3</Variable>
            <Variable name="satscore">satscoreTest3</Variable>
            <Variable name="kprepscore">krepscore3</Variable>           
        </VariableData>
    </StudentRequest>
    </StudentRequestList>
    </Root>
```

CSV is supposed to look like below

```
StudentFirstName,StudentLastName,StudentGrade,StudentHomeroomTeacher,Email, Hobby1, Hobby2,Hobby3, Hobby4, Hobby5, Hobby6, satscore, kprepscore     
Test1,TestLastName,3,WhiteTest1,test@email.com,TestHobby1,TestHobby2,TestHobby3,,,,satscoreTest1,krepscore1 
Test2,TestLastName2,3,WhiteTest1,test2@email.com,,,Hobby3,,Hobby5,Hobby6,satscoreTest2,krepscore2
Test1,TestLastName,3,WhiteTest1,test@email.com,,Hobby2,Hobby3,Hobby4,,,satscoreTest3,krepscore3
```

I am able to extract the values for nodes without attributes (as shown in code below) but for other nodes with attributes (variabledata/variable) struggling to get values so that i can create the csv file as shown above. Any suggestions are appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
  XDocument custOrd = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

                string csv =
                                    (from el in custOrd.Element("Root").Element("StudentRequestList").Elements("StudentRequest")
                                     select
                             String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}{5}",
                                 (string)el.Element("StudentFirstName"),
                                 (string)el.Element("StudentLastName"),
                                 (string)el.Element("StudentGrade"),
                                 (string)el.Element("StudentHomeroomTeacher"),
                                el.Element("VariableData").Element("Variable").Attribute("name").Value.Equals("Email") ? (string)el.Element("VariableData").Element("Variable") : null,                                
                                 Environment.NewLine
                             )
                                    )
                    .Aggregate(
                        new StringBuilder(),
                        (sb, s) => sb.Append(s),
                        sb => sb.ToString()
                    );
                Console.WriteLine(csv);
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: you mean, your code gives you just Email, but you want to get Hobby4...?

Comment: @Sajid i am not able to get any other after email, so looking for 1) how to get all the values 2) if Hobby5 is not there it needs to be populated as blank.

Comment: How about creating classes from your xml file (Edit / Paste Special / Paste XML As Classes) and deserializing? I have it working already

Comment: @OguzOzgul would you please be able to share your code?especially the deserializing part you are talking about. I am a newbie to c# & XML .Thanks.

Comment: Yes, when I also have it working with XDocument and XElements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small method that can wrap the attribute reading logic

```
private static string ValueOf(XElement el, string name)
{
    return (string)el.Element("VariableData")
        .Elements("Variable")
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Equals(name));
}
```

By employing this method in our select statement for each `<Variable>` element with different names, we can read all the variables that exist and return "" for the ones that don't.

I am also re-writing your string format template because it has insufficient number of parameters for what you want to write:

Now your select statement should look like this:

```
from el in custOrd.Element("Root").Element("StudentRequestList").Elements("StudentRequest")
select
    String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11},{12}",
        (string)el.Element("StudentFirstName"),
        (string)el.Element("StudentLastName"),
        (string)el.Element("StudentGrade"),
        (string)el.Element("StudentHomeroomTeacher"),
        ValueOf(el, "Email"), ValueOf(el, "Hobby1"), ValueOf(el, "Hobby2"), ValueOf(el, "Hobby3"),
        ValueOf(el, "Hobby4"), ValueOf(el, "Hobby5"), ValueOf(el, "Hobby6"),
        ValueOf(el, "satscore"),
        ValueOf(el, "kprepscore"),
        Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: Thanks @Oguz Ozgul, This worked like a charm. I have marked it as accepted answer. If you still have the code, i would be curious to see how you implemented using class and deserializing solution.  If you didn't save it , no worries

Comment: I will share it tomorrow for I have to leave now. Be safe.